# OS X Javascript Automation (JXA) Progress Bar

Tags: macos, applescript, progress-bar, progress, javascript-automation

In an Applescript applet, progress can be shown like so:

```
set progress description to "A simple progress indicator"
set progress additional description to "Preparing…"
set progress total steps to -1

delay 5

set progress total steps to 100
repeat with i from 1 to 100
    try
        set progress additional description to "I am on step " & i
        set progress completed steps to i
        delay 0.2
    on error thisErr
        display alert thisErr
        exit repeat
    end try
end repeat
```

How would you access `progress description`, `progress additional description`, and `progress total steps` in Javascript for Automation (JXA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `Progress` in this page --> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html

An example of script using the `Progress` object:

```
Progress.description =  "A simple progress indicator"
Progress.additionalDescription = "Preparing…"
delay(5)
Progress.totalUnitCount = 100;

for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    Progress.additionalDescription = "I am on step " + i
    Progress.completedUnitCount = i
    delay(0.1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the so-called "Progress Bar" provided by Yosemite is a joke.  It does not display what most people would expect:  A small window showing the progress.

Shane Stanley wrote the free [ASObjC Runner app](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner_vanilla.html) to provide this, and much more.

Take a look here for a real progress bar:
[Demo of real Progress Bar using ASObjC Runner app](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=43924)

This is written in AppleScript, but shouldn't be that hard to convert to JXA.

**EDIT: I have converted the AppleScript code to JXA. You can get it here:**

[Demo of a Real Progress Bar for JXA using ASObjC Runner app](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=184374#p184374)

[image]

Comment: IMO, the so-called "Progress Bar" provided by Yosemite is a joke. It does not display what most people would expect: A small window showing the progress. --> @JMichaelTX That's exactly what it does. Just File>Save as an application.

Comment: @Coder256:  That's find, but **by far most of my scripts**, and others I work with, **don't save the script as an app.**  I stand by my assessment.  I suppose it was you who gave me a down vote because you didn't like my comment.

Comment: I am amazed at how quickly people in this community are to make negative judgements and vote down both questions and answers they don't like.  I was trying to offer a helpful suggestion above, but someone doesn't seem to like it.  **If you made the vote down, have the integrity to post a comment stating why.**